# Sum/Intersection of Invariant Subspaces that have Invariant Complements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space, and let $M: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation. Suppose subspaces $S_1,S_2 \subset V$ are both $M$-invariant and have $M$-invariant complements (say $W_1$ and $W_2$, so $V = S_i \oplus W_i$).
**Question:** do the sum $S_1 + S_2$ and intersection $S_1 \cap S_2$ also have $M$-invariant complements?

I haven't yet found a valid proof or counterexample, and would appreciate any intuition (or proof or counterexample, of course) that anyone has towards this question. I know that the answer is yes if $M$ is diagonalizable or if the $W_i$ are actually the orthogonal complements. Can we do it without placing those restrictions?

Thanks!

---

*(Here's what I've tried so far.)*

My guess is that the answer is yes, and my proof attempts are inspired primarily by [Theorem 2.5.1 of this book](https://books.google.ca/books?id=LtbM8Ph1dnIC&lpg=PA108&dq=sum%20and%20intersection%20of%20coinvariant%20subspaces&pg=PA66#v=onepage&q&f=false).
The idea is to split $S_1$ and $S_2$ into irreducible subspaces (where an "irreducible subspace" is an $M$-invariant subspace that cannot be written as the direct sum of other $M$-invariant subspaces).
Before starting, also define a "supremal irreducible subspace" to be an irreducible subspace that is not a subset of any other irreducible subspace.
With that, here are the broad steps:

- I've shown that an invariant subspace has an invariant complement if and only if it is the direct sum of supremal irreducible subspaces.
  So the subspaces $S_1$ and $S_2$ can both be written as direct sums of supremal irreducible subspaces.
- Since $S_1$ and $S_2$ are both $M$-invariant, so are $S_1 + S_2$ and $S_1 \cap S_2$. Those sum and intersection can be written as direct sums of irreducible subspaces (by definition), but those irreducible subspaces are not necessarily supremal.
- If we can prove that those irreducible subspaces *are* supremal, then we're done... but I haven't had any luck with that so far. It's clearly dependent on choosing decompositions for $S_1$ and $S_2$ that fully characterize the supremal irreducible subspaces common to both of them.
- A first step might be to show that any two supremal irreducible subspaces are either equal or independent, and I think I can do the rest. Equivalently, we can show that if two Jordan chains have the same eigenvector and the same length, then their spans are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**False!** Counterexample: $V = \mathbb{R}^4$ and
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \,.
$$
Take the two $M$-invariant subspaces $S_i$ (and $M$-invariant complements $W_i$)
$$
S_1 = \mathrm{span} \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix} \right\} \,,\ 
S_2 = \mathrm{span} \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix} \right\} \,,\quad
W_1 = W_2 = \mathrm{span} \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\1\\1 \end{bmatrix} \right\} \,.
$$
The intersection $S_1 \cap S_2$ has only part of a Jordan chain for the top Jordan block of $M$, so it can't have an $M$-invariant complement. The sum $S_1 + S_2$ has only part of a Jordan chain for the bottom Jordan block of $M$, so it also can't have an $M$-invariant complement.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach might be to determine what the complements of the sum and intersections of the $S_i$'s are in terms of the $W_i$'s. Intuitively, I would imagine that the complement of $S_1+S_2$ is the intersection $W_1\cap W_2$ and the complement of the intersection $S_1\cap S_2$ is the sum $W_1 + W_2$.

From here, you might seek to invoke results involving invariance of sums and intersections of invariant subspaces.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately, that doesn't always work. The simple example is to take $V = \mathbb{R}^3$ and $M = I_3$ (the identity matrix), so *every* subspace of $V$ is $M$-invariant.

Then, take $S_1 = S_2 = span\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0)\}$, but $W_1 = span\{(0,0,1)\}$ and $W_2 = span\{(0,1,1)\}$. Then, $S_1 + S_2 = S_1$ (or $S_2$), but $W_1 \cap W_2 = \{ 0 \}$ (which isn't a complement at all).

Comment: With this example in mind, you will need to revisit the specific notion of complement subspaces. Notice that you do not have unique complements in this scenario and there are untold (uncountable) possible outcomes. You will likely be able to disprove this result if you don't stick with a stricter notion of subspace complement (like the perpendicular).

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into how I might "fix" the choice of complements up-front (hopefully without needing to resort to the perpendicular).

Comment: If you haven't been specifically dealing with perpendicular complements then the answer to your problem might look something like "This result holds for perpendicular compliments, but not any other form of set theoretic complement"